# Strings and Chars Invalid typecast in Delphi Berlin

Tags: string, delphi

I have a problem migrating a code from Delphi 7 to Delphi Berlin 10.1

This is the code running good on Delphi 7

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  S:String;
begin
  //MaskEdit1.Text:=FF; <- This is the variable string
  S:=#$5A+char(StrToInt(MaskEdit1.Text))+#$01#$00#$0D#$0A;
  ComPort1.WriteStr(S);
end;
```

Why `char()` does not work with Strings on Delphi Berlin 10.1?, I tried with `PAnsiChar()` and does not work neither
This is the error:

> [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(75): E2089 Invalid typecast

Comment: There is no way the code as shown would have worked in Delphi 7 to begin with, let alone be migrated to a later version. `char(MaskEdit1.Text)` is not a valid expression, because `char()` does not accept a `string` as input. `char` is a data type, the only thing that can be typecasted to a `char` like this is an integer value.

Comment: No, this does not "run good" in Delphi 7, nor in any other version of Delphi. Please post your real code.

Comment: You are right, there was a missing `StrToInt()` I edited it, that's is how it runs good in Delphi 7

Comment: adding strtoint also make no scence  too . if edit1.text is string like 'test' it will raise expetio. if it is ' 123456789' what you want with char(123456789)?if it is '8' it will be a #tab ...
I can not understand logic behid this code, even after your edit

Comment: The edit, is for numbers only (1,2,3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You couldn't *convert* text like **Hello** to a single char in real life, if someone asked you that for. So as the compiler cannot because it's impossible. You might wanted to write something like:

```
S := #$5A + MaskEdit1.Text[1] + #$01#$00#$0D#$0A;
```

where **[1]** is the index of the first char (hoping the only one that user can enter) of the mask edit text string. This assumes 1 based string char indexing which is default for desktop application compiler.